# Floor material reflections. How i may reduce them?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, reflection

[image]
How to reduce floor material regflection? Here is my nodes of floor texture

Comment: Is this floor one smooth plane? Because it does not look as if it had some bump map or normal map on it or the effect is very subtle. If you have textures for bump or normal, make sure the _Color Space_ is set to _Non-Color_, this is usually better... and maybe increase the _Strength_? You can also try to decrease the _Specular_ value (version 3.6.x or previous) or the _Specular_ > _IOR Level_ (since version 4.0) in the _Principled BSDF_. If you don't want it to be so glossy you can also increase the _Roughness_. Best would have been if you showed us a screenshot the material setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i changed the  Color Space is set to Non-Color.

Comment: I added my nodes of the texture maybe you can take a look?\